# Parsing XML and get required data from multiple tags with the same name using SAX parser in java

Tags: java, xml

```
<report xmlns="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/report/7.0/"
expressionLocale="en-us">
<modelPath>/content/package[@name=’GO Sales and Retailers’]
/model[@name=’model’]</modelPath>
<queries>
<query name="Query1">
<source>
<model/>
</source>
<selection>
<dataItem name="Revenue" aggregate="total">
<expression>[gosales_goretailers].[Orders].[Revenue]</expression>
</dataItem>
<dataItem name="Sales territory" aggregate="none">
<expression>[gosales_goretailers].[Countries].[Sales territory]
</expression>
</dataItem>
<dataItem name="Order method" aggregate="none">
<expression>[gosales_goretailers].[Orders].[Order method]</expression>
</dataItem>
<dataItem name="Order year" aggregate="none">
<expression>[gosales_goretailers].[Orders].[Order year]</expression>
</dataItem>
<dataItem name="Product line" aggregate="none">
<expression>[gosales_goretailers].[Products].[Product line]</expression>
</dataItem>
```

i want to store the text value within the expression tag with its corresponding data item value using SAX parser.

means i want the output like this:
(1) Revenue=[gosales_goretailers].[Orders].[Revenue]
(2) Sales territory=[gosales_goretailers].[Countries].[Sales territory]...

I used the following code to store all text values in a list within the Expression tag

```
       final ArrayList<String> dataItemList=new ArrayList<String>();
        final ArrayList<String> expressionList=new ArrayList<String>();
        final ArrayList<String> retList=new ArrayList<String>();

        try
        {
        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();


        DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {

            String retData="";
            boolean bDataItem = false;
            boolean bExpression=false; 


            public void startElement(String uri, String localName,String qName, 
                        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {



                if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("dataitem")) {
                    bDataItem = true;

                    String name=attributes.getValue("name");

                    if(!dataItemList.contains(name))
                    {
                    dataItemList.add(name);
                    retData=name;
                    }

                }
                if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("expression")) {
                    bExpression = true;

                }

            }


            public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {

                if (bExpression) {

                    String exp=new String(ch, start, length);
                    if(!expressionList.contains(exp))
                    {
                        expressionList.add(exp);
                        retData+="@@sep@@"+exp;
                        retList.add(retData);
                        retData="";
                    }
                    bExpression = false;
                }
            }

             };
             InputSource is=new InputSource(new StringReader(strXML));
             saxParser.parse(is, handler);
```

But it is printing only the text value from the first expression tag and also its not printing the full text

output is coming :
Expression List = {[gosales_goretailers}

Comment: maybe you mean like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3822659/217324)? also if it's not printing the full text it might be because your characters method doesn't handle the case where element text is delivered in more than one call..

Comment: if you want the list to contain distinct values, it is better to make it a `Set` and the implementation a `HashSet`. possibly it can solve the problem

Comment: @sharonbn the main problem is i am not getting the full text within the expression tag. i want to get the expression text value with corresponding data item value

Comment: @NathanHughes would you plz give me some solution regarding How to configure the characters method?

Comment: see if this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567636/java-sax-parser-split-calls-to-characters

Comment: if the characters method is your problem, the post sharonbn linked to has the answer to that. otherwise please edit and be clearer about what the issue is. you may need to keep track of the current path in your xml, the post i linked to in a previous comment has answers that describe several ways to do that.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567636/java-sax-parser-split-calls-to-characters), it is possible that the parser will call characters() method multiple times.